# Loosing mouse cursor when changing GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH) to GetStockObject(GREY_BRUSH)

Tags: c, winapi

I am trying to learn win32 API using Programming Windows fifth Edition.
As I was experimenting with some Identifiers I noticed something that I am not able to understand why is happening.I` ll be more specific, here is my code:

```
#include<Windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int 
WINAPI 
WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
    static TCHAR szAppName[] = TEXT("HELLOWIN");
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG msg;
    WNDCLASS wndclass;

    wndclass.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wndclass.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wndclass.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wndclass.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wndclass.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wndclass.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_SHIELD);
    wndclass.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_CROSS);
    wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wndclass.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
    wndclass.lpszClassName = szAppName;

    if (!RegisterClass(&wndclass))
    {
        MessageBox(0, TEXT("This Programm Requires WINNT!"), szAppName, MB_ICONERROR);
        return(0);
    }

    hwnd = CreateWindow(szAppName,   //window class name
        TEXT("The Hello Program"),   //window caption
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,         //window style
        CW_USEDEFAULT,               //initial x position
        CW_USEDEFAULT,               //initial y position   
        CW_USEDEFAULT,               //initial x size
        CW_USEDEFAULT,               //initial y size
        NULL,                        //parent window handle(we have top-level window)
        NULL,                        //window menu handle
        hInstance,                   //programm instances handle    
        NULL);                       //creation parameters                          

    ShowWindow(hwnd, iCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;


}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HDC hdc;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    RECT rect;

    switch (message)
    {

        case WM_CREATE:
        {
            PlaySound(TEXT("D:\\mp3\\aywy._&_EphRem_-_Adderall.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
            return 0;
        } break;

        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);

            DrawText(hdc, TEXT("Hello, Windows 98!"), -1, &rect, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);
            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            return 0;
        } break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        } break;

    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

With this code everything works great and as expected but...
when i change:

```
wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
```

to

```
wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(GRAY_BRUSH);
```

the cursor icon is lost on the background and is only visisble in the small line
in which i use drawText().What confuses me is that this doesnt happen when my background is white(WHITE_BRUSH).

Could someone explain why?

PS:If this behaviour is explained later in the book (I am finishing chapter 3 currently) just type Read more so i don`t waste you time.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is probably happening is that the 'cross' cursor that you are using is a very thin cursor implemented (either by windows or by the hardware) by NEGating the underlying pixels instead of painting above them.  This works fine for all colors except the 0x808080 gray, because negating 0x808080 still gives 0x808080, so the cursor is invisible.  Try using light gray, dark gray, or another cursor which is not so thin.

Comment: You are correct.When changing the cursor identifier back to IDC_ARROW(Default white arrow windows cursor) i can see the cursor again.Thank you.

Comment: Glad to be of help.  Please accept the answer (and up-vote if you wish.)

Comment: I m trying to upvote but i need more reputation.Once i get to 15 i will come back to upvote

Comment: C-:= ok, don't worry about it.  Happy stackoverflowing!

Comment: There you go my friend :)